# Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'report-sample'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified Next js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, next.js, content-security-policy

It's been more than a week or so, I started with the React js Framework Next.js and I am really enjoying how simple and powerful it is.

I have few pages that I have built with next.js Every page is working fine other than the page that has a Google Maps embed. I saw a few strange warnings inside the google console and I couldn't find a way to read those errors, I went straight to Mozilla Brower and I got 20+ warnings that are supposed to be fixed. But i really don't have any idea how to fix those

So many warnings like this!!

**Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'report-sample'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified**